# Segmentation fault in inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, coredump

I want to move an assembly code from .S to the c++ code(inline).
The assembly works correctly when I use .S file.

```
extern "C" int  libucontext_getcontext(libucontext_ucontext_t *);
.
.
.
template<class C,class ... Args> int thread_create(C(*f), Args... r) {

Thread* t;
t = new Thread;
t->ucontext_ptr = new libucontext_ucontext_t;

libucontext_getcontext(t->ucontext_ptr);
t->stack = new char [STACK_SIZE];
t->ucontext_ptr->uc_stack.ss_sp = t->stack;
t->ucontext_ptr->uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
t->ucontext_ptr->uc_stack.ss_flags = 0;
t->ucontext_ptr->uc_link = NULL;
static const std::size_t value = sizeof...(Args);}
```

and the .S file

```
#include "defs.h"

ALIAS(getcontext, libucontext_getcontext)
ALIAS(__getcontext, libucontext_getcontext)

FUNC(libucontext_getcontext)
/* load address of the ucontext structure */
movl    4(%esp), %eax

/* EAX is not a preserved register */
movl    $0, REG_OFFSET(REG_EAX)(%eax)

/* copy all of the current registers into the ucontext structure */
movl    %ecx, REG_OFFSET(REG_ECX)(%eax)
movl    %ebx, REG_OFFSET(REG_EBX)(%eax)
movl    %edx, REG_OFFSET(REG_EDX)(%eax)
movl    %edi, REG_OFFSET(REG_EDI)(%eax)
movl    %esi, REG_OFFSET(REG_ESI)(%eax)
movl    %ebp, REG_OFFSET(REG_EBP)(%eax)

/* the first argument on the stack is the jump target (%eip), so we store it in the EIP
   register in the ucontext structure. */
movl    (%esp), %ecx
movl    %ecx, REG_OFFSET(REG_EIP)(%eax)

/* take the stack pointer address (%esp) offsetting by 4 to skip over the jump target. 
*/
leal    4(%esp), %ecx
movl    %ecx, REG_OFFSET(REG_ESP)(%eax)

/* finally, save the FS segment register */
xorl    %ecx, %ecx
movw    %fs, %cx
movl    %ecx, REG_OFFSET(REG_FS)(%eax)

/* we're all done here, return 0 */
xorl    %eax, %eax
ret
END(libucontext_getcontext)
```

I want to use inline assembly in the source code but it gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
for example the sinlge inline code in below resulted to core dump.

```
int  libucontext_getcontext(libucontext_ucontext_t *oucp){
asm ("movl 4(%esp), %eax");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: This will not really be achievable.  Inline assembly is subject to complex compiler optimisations and transformations.  You do not have the level of control needed to write this kind of routine.

Comment: You can't safely write a context-switch function in inline asm; there's no way to tell the compiler the stack pointer is clobbered.  (Except in `__attribute__((naked))` which is basically the same thing as a `.S` file, except the C++ compiler handles name mangling. 
 Or at global scope still using an asm label for the function name).  The trick with making it a separate function is that it eventually returns just like a normal function, after some other thread switches back to this saved context.

Comment: I'm surprised `asm ("movl 4(%esp), %eax");` segfaults on that instruction, though; perhaps you're building it as 64-bit code.  Of course, it could segfault on a later instruction after inlining into a caller; GCC will assume that EAX still has its old value because you didn't declare a clobber on EAX.

Comment: Or did you not actually look at the core-dump or run it under GDB to see where it segfaulted?  That's always step 1 when debugging assembly; debuggers work very well for asm because the human level matches the machine level 1:1.  I guess you didn't actually say it segfaulted there, and you could have compiled with optimization enabled.  Not that it matters really; the whole approach is a non-starter, and seems pointless.  Harder to get right if it's possible at all, probably harder to maintain (e.g. adding new clobbers as future CPUs get new registers like AVX-512 k0..k7) vs. stand-alone asm.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks for your help. I should add -m32 in gcc command line as you mentioned and    'asm ("movl 4(%esp), %eax");' code works without error. but I want to use this source code in another compiler for HLS . that compiler does not support 32 bit. So I want to know is it possible to have the same functionality for getcontext and setcontext  methodos in ucontext.h library (like .S file)by writing code in c/c++?

Comment: Absolutely not.  Swapping the stack pointer is always going to be machine-specific, and not something that C or C++ compilers give you built-ins / intrinsics for.  You'll need a different version of the asm for context-switching on every different calling convention for every different ISA.  (Although your current code redundantly saves a bunch of call-clobbered registers that the compiler will assume are destroyed by calling a function, like ECX and EDX, but not EAX.)